# PHP mysqli DB connection: error messages

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

I am testing the die () clause in the below code. When I enter an incorrect password and use the **mysqli_connect_error()** function, everything works as expected and I get the MySQL error message. Why does it not work when I use **mysqli_error()**? I was under the impression mysqli_error() should return the last error description, regardless of error type, for the most recent function call? Im using PHP 5.2.17

This works:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","testUser","incorrectPassword","testDB") 
or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

This does not work:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","testUser","incorrectPassword","testDB")
or die(mysqli_error());
```

Would like to understand why.

Comment: I believe it is because the mysqli_error() needs a valid DB link.  That function is to check errors from queries, not connection errors.

Comment: It seems like there is a special property for *connect* errors: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php

Answer (score 0):

It needs the connection mysqli_error($link).

The mysqli_error() function is identical to the corresponding mysqli_errno() function in every way, except instead of returning an integer error code the mysqli_error() function will return a string representation of the last error to occur for the database connection represented by the link parameter. If no error has occured, this function will return an empty string.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

One is for the connection the other 2 for query errors.